# Extending User Entity using Keycloak in JHipster

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, jhipster, openid-connect, keycloak

I want to add additional info when I register a new JHipster User with Keycloak. I already created an ExtendedUser entity with an one-to-one Relationship to the default User. Now i want to "extend" the registration form provided by Keycloak (adress, city,etc.) and safe these values in the ExtendedUser. is this possible? I cant seem to find any info on this. Also the registration form itself isn't in the gateway (like the default), but on the "keycloak-side", so i dont know if i can access the added values. My first guess would be to add the additional fields to the registration form, and then add the values to the token claims, which i could use to create an ExtendedUser in the background.

I´m using the default Keycloak implementation provided by JHipster (docker).

If this is not possible are there any other ways this could work (maybe switching to the JWT security implementation)? I also tried using the UAA server, but this isn't working for me because of other reasons.

Comment: The UserService handles saving user data to the database. However, you don't really need to store all the user's attributes in JHipster's database since the values are never rendered or used in a JHipster app. User data is only put into the database do you can establish relationships with the user. Ideally, you keep all your user data in your identity provider. In this case, that's Keycloak.

Comment: @MattRaible thanks for answering. I use the extended user as an "profile" entity, to safe additional info about the user, which i want to use in my JHipster app. Problem is, i want to add the additional user info while registering a new user via keycloak. After some research i think i need a custom template for keycloak to be able to add additional info, but i dont know how i'm able to send these values to my JHipster app. If this is possible how can i create 2 entites (user and profile) after registering a new user? Would you recommend to stick with this approach?

Comment: UserService#syncUserWithIdP is where you could save additional fields. If you store them as claims in your ID token, you should be able to read them. The UserService#getUserFromAuthentication method is what handles grabbing the attributes from the token.

Comment: please is there any example @MattRaible @xBoLLo?

Comment: No, I do not have an example, but `getUserFromAuthentication()` calls [`getUser()`](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/service/UserService.java.ejs#L1031), which shows how you can get claims from the ID token (aka the details map).